# preg_match_all and multiple language

Tags: preg-match-all, multilingual

I have the following bit of code.

```
$pattern = '~[a-z0-9]+~';
preg_match_all($pattern, "some text from a website", $array);
```

Which works fine for en - The English Language or USA American Engish, but **how do I make this work for ALL other languages**? I have detected chaset and language from html.

EDIT: I think I have to use http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php - http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Anyone know how I match (a-z0-9) in any language using Unicode Regular Expressions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to use code Regular Expressions A pattern that represents [a-z0-9] in any language is :

```
$pattern = '~[\p{L}\p{Nd}]+~';
```

Very useful article here : http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html